# Redirect requests for specific domain to local ip adress of docker container

Tags: linux, networking, docker, linux-networking

I have a docker container running flask on port 5000.
I wanted that container to be publicly accessed, so I bound the port with:`-p 5000:5000`, and I run flask with: `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`. This does what I needed, but my server hosts multiple websites on separated domains, and this made all of them listen on the port 5000.

How can I make only the requests coming for a specific domain open port 5000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your Docker container with port 5000 exposed will make it available on the host to everybody accessing that host as you found out.

You could run a reverse proxy container like nginx exposing 5000 to the host then forward appropriately to your flask container internally.